# git and sshfs: status is inaccurate

Tags: git, sshfs

I am mounting a git repository on a virtual machine over sshfs onto my host machine. So far so good. However, git claims that there are many uncommitted changes when viewing the repository over sshfs.

*Why is that?*

The relevant bit from `/etc/fstab`, if that helps:

```
sshfs#usr@virtual:/home/user/repos /home/user/repos/ fuse noauto,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0,workaround=rename 0 0
```

Note: *Cloning, push, and pull operations could done instead but the code needs to compile on the virtual machine OS and not on the host machine -- long story, it **has** to be this way.  I do not fancy doing a commit per compile, that's just silly.*

Answer (score 2):

It seems like both FUSE and sshfs will change inodes out from under you. A quick Google search suggests adding `-o workaround=rename` (sshfs) and `-o noforget` (FUSE) to your mount options.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why it does not work.  However, neither options as added to `/etc/fstab` makes a difference.